# scikit learn task managment library

Tags: scikit-learn

Update:
after some extra search. I thin I am overuse scikit-learn. if I want a production ML tools. I should use something like mahout which built on hadoop. scikit-learn is more like a toy tools for experiment ideas.

I am new to scikit-learn. I try to use scikit-learn to train a model, I want to experiment different feature combinationes and data pre-processing techniques. Each experiment will takes few hours(in order to minimize error, I will run every experiment 10 times with different train-test split), So I wrote some python script to run experiment one by one automatically, when an experiment is done, it will send me an email.

It works well, I found another server that is available to run my experiment today, it seems reasonable I should write some script that can run experiments in a distribution-fashion. There are big data platforms like hadoop, but I find that it is not for python and scikit-learn(please point out to me If my understanding of hadoop is wrong).

Because scikit-learn is an "old" library, so I think there should have existing libraries that have these capabilities that I want. or I am running in wrong direction of scikit-learn?

I try to google "scikit-learn task managment", But nothing I want turn out. other key word to search is also very welcome.

Comment: Do you want to submit jobs (run scripts) on a server for example ? What do you mean by saying "task manager" ?

Comment: I have a lot experiment to runs. Then most efficient way to do that is run them automatically on any server that is available. I can write scripts to do that, in fact My script work well on single machine. But before I continue to write script to distribute tasks on several server. I want to know if there is libraries or tools that have this kind of capabiltiies. OR, If these requirement is not  a way that scikit-learn do things.

Comment: Have you looked into using Dask with Scikit-learn? https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/02/07/dask-sklearn-simple

Comment: Hi Christopher, this post give me some ideas of what I should do next.  all I have to do is write some script,  so I can add task any time when I have some new idea.  So the server will will run it when existing task is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See "Experimentation frameworks" at http://scikit-learn.org/dev/related_projects.html

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want.